Power Apps: PDF - Expand Containers not working for Gallery and Container
It would be much appreciated if you would help me on this.
I have screen consist of one main container (ResultMainContainer_Test), one left sub-container(LeftContainer_Test) and one right sub-container (RightContainer_Test), and a Gallery was included in the RightContainer.
The Gallery contains list of information which cannot show in one page. I want to export the main container to one pdf file, including all the information listed in the Gallery.
When the "Proceed Next" button was selected, it will generate a pdf file and send for approval by Power Automate (ApprovalEmail). Please find the code below:
    Set(
    PDFContent,
    {
        ContentBytes: PDF(
            ResultMainContainer_Test,
            {
                Orientation: PaperOrientation.Portrait,
                Size: PaperSize.A4,
                DPI: 150,
                ExpandContainers: true
            }
        ),
        Name: "Executive Summary.pdf",
file: {
    contentBytes: PDF(ResultMainContainer_Test),ExpandContainers: true,Orientation: PaperOrientation.Portrait,
                Size: PaperSize.A4,
                DPI: 150,
    name: "Executive Summary.pdf" 
}
 
    }
);
 
ApprovalEmail.Run("Executive Summary.pdf","Please review and approve.", "Approver email","[Approval request],User().Email,User().FullName,PDFContent);

Although ExpandContainers: true, it is not working and only showing the screen as shown below. Is there anything wrong with the code? thanks a lot for your help.


